# Page Transition Effect to External URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, transition

I have two domains that are closely related to each other. Because of this I'm putting a fixed box on the top right corner of the page so that users can quickly jump between the two sites. However I would like to add a page transition to this action so that when the user clicks the link in the box the site will gracefully transition to the new URL.

I know you can do this with internal pages via JQuery Mobile ( http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html ), however the limitation is that the link has to be ajax, and can not be activated to new URL's.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this? Ideally I would like to use the "Flow" or "Slide" transition. However I'll take any example or reference you can provide and adapt it to my needs.

The solution does not necessarily need to be jQuery, it can be javascript, HTML 5, CSS or any other solution that may work.

Thanks,
~Andrew

Answer (score 0):

For me it would work something like this:

Pseudo HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="page1"> <!-- Content goes here --> </div>
</body>
```

Pseudo JQuery:

```
on AJAX complete {
   var newID
   var oldID
   if ($('#page1').length) { // Work out old and new ID's
      newID = 'page2'
      oldID = 'page1'
   } else {
      newID = 'page1'
      oldID = 'page2'
   }
   $('body').append('<div id="' + newID +'" style="display:none;">' + DataFromAjaxCall + '</div>') // Append the body with a hidden div containing new content
   $('#' + oldID).fadeOut(400, function() { // Fade the old one out and then remove it
      $(this).remove();
   });
   $('#' + newID).fadeIn(400); // Fade the new one in
}
```